# How to create a vector of templated Interface with multiple template arg types?

Tags: c++, templates

As it looks from the code below, I am trying to create a vector of `ITemmplateInterface` and add to it multiple derived classes of different specializations.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Template interface
template <typename T>
class ITemplateInterface {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual T getValue() const = 0;
    virtual ~ITemplateInterface() = default;

    using type = T;
};

// Derived class 1
class DerivedClass1 : public ITemplateInterface<std::string> {
public:
    void foo() override {
        std::cout << "DerivedClass1 foo" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string getValue() const override {
        return std::string{};
    }
};

// Derived class 2
class DerivedClass2 : public ITemplateInterface<int> {
public:
    void foo() override {
        std::cout << "DerivedClass2 foo" << std::endl;
    }

    int getValue() const override {
        return 0;
    }
};

// Base class pointer type
using ITemplateInterfacePtr = ITemplateInterface<void*>;

int main() {
    // Vector of pointers to the base interface
    std::vector<ITemplateInterfacePtr*> myVector;

    // Instantiate objects of derived classes
    DerivedClass1 obj1;
    DerivedClass2 obj2;

    // Add objects to the vector
    myVector.push_back(&obj1);
    myVector.push_back(&obj2);

    // Use the objects through the vector
    for (const auto& item : myVector) {
        // Dereference the base class pointer
        auto const value = item->getValue();
        std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I have tried is to create a vector with a `void*` as template argument but unable to achieve the desired result. Also tried to use `ITemplateInterface::type` but that did not work either. Also tried with `std::reference_wrapper`, again with no success. I also thought of using the `std::any` instead of `void*`.

How can I create this vector and use it as you see in the `for` block?

Comment: if you want runtime polymorphism then `DerivedClass1` and `DerivedClass2` should have a common base. `ITemplateInterface<int>` and `ITemplateInterface<std::string>` are two completely different types. The fact that they are instantiations of the same template does not help here, unless you make all instantiations of `ITemplateInterface` inherit from some common base class

Comment: though reading about `std::variant` and `std::visit` might give you some ideas for different design

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I also thought of `std::variant`. Still I am actually using `etl` library which has a limit of 8 variants. I have way more than 8 variants for this.

Comment: `auto const value = item->getValue();` you seem to expect `auto` to do some magic here, but if you cannot write the actual type in place of `auto` then the compiler cannot do it is well. You can either make it `int` or `std::string`, it cannot be both. In other words, you first need to make up your mind on how you are going to use the vector. That then determines what to store as elements.

Comment: the deeper issue is that you confuse runtime with compile time polymorhpism

Comment: limit of 8? How about a `variant< variant<A1,...A8>,variant<A9....A16>>` then?

Comment: indeed that would go to 8^2 = 64 variants. I don't know. It might work!?

Comment: do you see an option to use the inheritance differently?

Comment: whats the actual problem you are trying to solve? This looks very much like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because frankly, your usage of the template interface is based on a misunderstanding and cannot work the way you intend when `getValue` should return different types

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256556/discussion-between-codiac-and-463035818-is-not-an-ai).